# Cannot Pass Argument to /bin/sh

Tags: cocoa, shell, unix, arguments, nstask

I'm writing a command line helper for one of my cocoa apps. This helper tool is supposed to execute an instance of shell ( /bin/sh ) using `NSTask`. As you all know it's possible to execute `sh` taking advantage of `-c`, you can pass one or more command as an argument to be executed.

For example running `/bin/sh -c "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on"`

executes `networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on` .

Now, Here's the question :

When I set the launch path to `sh` ( `[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"]` ) , and then set Arguments as following :

```
cmd = "-c,\\\"networksetup\\_-setwebproxystate\\_Wi-Fi\\_on\\\"";
stringArguments = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cmd.c_str()];
stringArguments = [[stringArguments stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "] mutableCopy];
arguments = [stringArguments componentsSeparatedByString:@","];        
[task setArguments:arguments];
```

I see that somehow `-c` argument is skipped, because I get the following error :

`/bin/sh: "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on": command not found`

and that's because `"networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on"` is executed directly not as an argument after `sh -c`.

I know I couldn't explain in the clearest way possible, but hope I could deliver what I meant.

I tried almost everything came to my mind, but I'm stuck with this. Any suggestions is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your amazingly convoluted way of specifying the command string.
NSTask does not need quotes around the arguments.  You are ending up with arguments containing this:

```
[0] ==> -c

[1] ==> "networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on"
```

Note the double-quotes.
Why not just use

```
 arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    @"-c",
    @"networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on",
    nil ];
```

Comment: `NSTask` does not need double quotes, `sh -c` DOES NEED.
I first had lots of problems to pass `"` in arguments because it was ignored when I was passing it like `\"`, But passing another `\\`` before solved it and now I'm dealing with this !
Try executing commands with `sh -c` and you will notice what I say. ( For one example you can combine commands like `sh -c "firstCommand && secondCommand" so existence of quotes is necessary ) ;)

Comment: And by the way, the reason that I wrote `cmd = ...` like that is that, `cmd` is being set from a value that `cin>>` is receiving, so that's not as easy as it sounds to pass parameters :D

Comment: No, Unkn0wn, 'sh -c' does *not* need double quote in and of itself.  The command-line-processor that you are typing it into does.  What 'sh -c' requires is a SINGLE ARGUMENT which is the entire command to be parsed and executed.  If that command requires its own quotes, then fine.

And I can't see why you need so many backslashes - I suspect you may be confusing what is displayed by your logging mechanism with what is actually in your variables...

Answer (score 1):

When entering a command at the shell prompt double-quotes are used to pass a string as a *single* argument when it would otherwise be passed as multiple arguments. When using `NSTask` (or function/system calls in the `exec` family) you pass each argument individually, the shell does not need to parse a command line, and so double quotes are not required. The following fragment:

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];

[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];

[task setArguments:@[@"-c", @"networksetup -setwebproxystate Wi-Fi on"]];

[task launch];
```

will do the task you want. The two arguments are passed using a literal array expression, each argument is just a string and may contain spaces etc.

HTH